# IFERROR with 3 values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a VLOOKUP for postcodes and currently it works when searching for both 3 and 4 character postcodes
e.g.
TW13 - Feltham
UB3 - Uxbridge

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,4)&"*",Postcodes!A:C,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,3)&"*",Postcodes!A:C,3,FALSE))
```

But I forgot that there are 2 character postcodes and both `VLOOKUP` and `IFERROR` only allow two checks to be made.

So where should I be looking to first check for 4 characters, then 3 characters or worst case 2 characters? If it helps all my postcodes are in the correct format with the space e.g. TW13 9XX, UB3 4XJ, W3 4EE.

Comment: Put another `IFERROR` in the `value_if_error` part of the first `IFERROR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just nest in another `IFERROR()` in the `value_if_error` clause of the first:

```
=
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,4)&"*",Postcodes!A:C,3,FALSE),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,3)&"*",Postcodes!A:C,3,FALSE),
        VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,2)&"*",Postcodes!A:C,3,FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just extracting the part prior to the breaking space in postcodes

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,FIND(" ",F2)-1)&"*",Postcodes!A:C,3,FALSE),"")
```